# Convert JSON (Object) to Array - Power automate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

In a power automate flow that I'm currently creating, I need to read the body of a specific email, previously I used the Get Emails V3 and that works great but the Get Emails widget only takes 25 emails at most.
So right now I'm using a workaround with Send an HTTP Request, but the outputs of that are in JSON and for the flow to work I need an array.

[image]

What can I do to save the JSON objects into a array?

What can I do to save the JSON objects into a array? this is the flow that I'm using

[image]

or is there a way to convert the JSON into HTML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your response from the send HTTP request and we’ll tell you what to do. If there are 25 items coming back, there’s an array in there somewhere.

Comment: Hi, 
The HTTP request returns around 13 emails thats because there is 13 in my email, but that is just for testing. The real inbox has 300+ emails. But the Get Emails V3 only returns to 25 emails max, so thats why i am working on a workaround. i edited the post and added the code it returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify this as your expression into the loop ...

```
body('Send_an_HTTP_request')?['value']
```

That should give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you! it almost works now, but one more thing, now it picks the same email 13 times. do you know what i have to do so it picks a new email body every time?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#item

item() will give you the current item in the array when it’s looping. From here, you can refer to a property in each item by the same syntax as I’ve already provided, e.g. item()?[‘propertyName’] … if my answer works, please flag it so. It rewards those who help and helps others who are looking for the same answer.